# Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import firebase from "../api/firebase";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

export default function ListItem(props) {
  const commentRef = useRef();

  const addCommentHandler = async () => {
    const comment = commentRef.current.value;
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    // const jajaja = await db.collection("userData").doc(`${props.id}`).get();
    // console.log(jajaja.data().comments.length);
    const init = db.collection("userData").doc(`${props.id}`);

    const init2 = await init.update(
      { comments: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(`${comment}`) },
      {
        merge: true,
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li onClick={props.onClick}>{props.email}</li>
      <input type="text" ref={commentRef} />
      <button onClick={addCommentHandler}>Add Comment</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

> I keep getting the title as the error. What am I doing wrong? Also, here's a snapshot of my database. I already have added one comment in firestore already and am trying to add more "comments" array items.
> [image: This is my cloud firestore database. I'm trying to add new comments in my comments array]

This is the error after using set() instead of update()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `{merge: true}` in the `.update()`. The update method is used when you know the document exists else it'll return an error.

```
const init2 = await init.set(
      { comments: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(`${comment}`) },
      {
        merge: true,
      }
    );
```

You are probably looking for `.set()`. It'll will create a document if absent but will update existing document without overwriting other fields.

The best way would be to use update if you know document exists and it would look like:

```
const init2 = await init.update({ comments:admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(`${comment}`) }
```

Note again, you don't need to pass the merge option when using update.

Comment: I got the same error, instead of DocumentReference.update(), I got DocumentReference.set().    Also, I'm able to add primitive datatypes normally but arrays and maps are causing problems.

Comment: @Darius I'd like to see a screenshot of the error.